# What is CallerReference for when posting an invalidation request to Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

The [Amazon CloudFront documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/) doesn't mention what the "CallerReference" is for or what I should fill it with, the examples I have seen on other sites use a guid or the current date.

The [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) tooltip says it's to prevent replay attacks, but that's what the date header is for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Amazon CloudFront Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html?r=5082) (meanwhile?!) states that CallerReference is *A unique name that ensures the request can't be replayed* indeed, see [InvalidationBatch Complex Type](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/InvalidationBatchDatatype.html?r=9424) for details:

> If the CallerReference is a value you already sent in a previous
>   invalidation batch request, and if the content of each Path element is
>   identical to the original request, the response includes the same
>   information returned to the original request.
>
> If the CallerReference is a value you already sent in a previous
>   invalidation batch request but the content of any Path is different
>   from the original request, CloudFront returns an
>   InvalidationBatchAlreadyExists error.

Section *Caller Reference* within Object Invalidation confirms this as well and provides a hint how to handle it in practice:

> CallerReference is a unique value that you provide and that CloudFront
>   uses to prevent replays of your request. You must provide a new caller
>   reference value and other new information in the request for
>   CloudFront to create a new invalidation request. You could use a time
>   stamp for the caller reference (such as 20100801090000).

Despite the sample using a time stamp as well, a dedicated value to handle replay attacks supposedly provides more flexibility and thus potentially increased security (if so desired) than relying on a date header.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents for someone reading this in futuer:

CallerReference is also useful with complex and automated cloud based setup. Think of a deployment setup with many scripts from different hosts are running independently to verifying and creating CloudFront distribution. In such case you want only one create request to be successful. You can use fixed CallerReference to make sure you don't create duplicate distribution accidentally.